# How to derive means and sds and anova for this data in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have been given this raw data to use in Spss and i'm so confused since i'm used to R instead.
An experiment monitored the amount of weight gained by anorexic girls after various treatments. Girls were placed to assigned to one of three groups. Group 1 had no therapy, Group 2 had cognitive behaviour therapy. Group 3 had family therapy. The researchers wanted to know if the two treatment groups produced weight gain relative to the control group.

This is the data

> group1<- c(-9.3,-5.4,12.3,-2,-10.2,-12.2,11.6,-7.1,6.2,9.2,8.3,3.3,11.3,-10.6,-4.6,-6.7,2.8,3.7,15.9,-10.2)
>   group2<-c(-1.7,-3.5,14.9,3.5,17.1,-7.6,1.6,11.7,6.1,-4,20.9,-9.1,2.1,-1.4,1.4,-3.7,2.4,12.6,1.9,3.9,15.4)
>   group3<-c(11.4,11.0,5.5,9.4,13.6,-2.9,7.4,21.5,-5.3,-3.8,13.4,13.1,9,3.9,5.7,10.7)

I have been asked to come up with the mean and stdeviation of the independant variable which i believe is the treatment groups as a function of weight. 
then do anova for the data and pairwise comparisons

i dont know where to start with this data besides putting it in the SPSS
with R i would use summary and anova functions but with the SPSS im lost.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

For comparison of means and one-way ANOVA (and all of the potential options) navigate the menus for Analyze -> Compare Means. Below is an example using Tukey post-hoc comparisons. In the future just search the command syntax reference. A search for ANOVA would have told you all you needed to know.

```
DATA LIST FREE (",") / val.
BEGIN DATA
-9.3,-5.4,12.3,-2,-10.2,-12.2,11.6,-7.1,6.2,9.2,8.3,3.3,11.3,-10.6,-4.6,-6.7,2.8,3.7,15.9,-10.2
-1.7,-3.5,14.9,3.5,17.1,-7.6,1.6,11.7,6.1,-4,20.9,-9.1,2.1,-1.4,1.4,-3.7,2.4,12.6,1.9,3.9,15.4
11.4,11.0,5.5,9.4,13.6,-2.9,7.4,21.5,-5.3,-3.8,13.4,13.1,9,3.9,5.7,10.7
END DATA.
DATASET NAME val.
DO IF $casenum <= 20.
  COMPUTE grID = 1.
ELSE IF $casenum > 20 AND $casenum <= 41.
  COMPUTE grID = 2.
ELSE.
  COMPUTE grID = 3.
END IF.

*Means and Standard Deviations.
MEANS
  TABLES=val  BY grID
  /CELLS MEAN COUNT STDDEV  .

*Anova.
ONEWAY val BY grID
  /MISSING ANALYSIS
  /POSTHOC = TUKEY ALPHA(.05).
```